# unix script to search subdirectories for a file

Tags: unix

This script checks if the  exists in the  and also if the modification date is less than 1 day. I have been trying to make it traverse the whole directory to look for the file I have tried test and find but am not very familiar with unix scripting.

please advise what the correct syntax or command is, the script works fine if the file I am looking for is in the upload directory.

**Problem**
I would like to search all subdirectories for the file below the upload directory? :o)
I am using a mac terminal as unix environment.

```
filename=help.csv

filedir="localhost/upload/"

cd $filedir

# if [ find . -name "$filename" ]; then
if [ -e "$filename" ]; then               # what should I add here to find the file in   any subdirectory of upload

  echo "File Exists"
  filestr=`find . -name $filename -mtime +1 -print`
  if [ "$filestr" = "" ]; then
    echo "File is not older than 1 day"
  else
    echo "File is older than 1 day"
  fi
else

  echo "File does not exist"
fi

exit 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You should just be able to start `find` in the upload directory.

```
find /path/to/upload/dir -name $filename -mtime +1 -print
```

The `.` you have now in your invocation just means "start looking in .", which is the current directory.

Comment: I have ammended my script if [ find /localhost/upload/ -name "$filename" -mtime +1 -print ]; then  however I just get an error "too  many arguments" any ideas? is my syntax correct.

Comment: Does the `find` command work from the command line?  I suspect you are just constructing the `find` incorrectly.

Comment: I believe Andy was suggesting that you replace your entire script with just the `find` command he wrote.  No `if`s, or `[]`s ... just run the `find` command manually.

Comment: No the command does not work from the command line. this command works fine, find . -name "*.csv"

Comment: when I enter find /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/data_vis/upload/ -name Audit_Summary.csv -mtime +1 -print nothing is returned

Comment: Is the file actually there?  Can you see it from directory listings?